# Show then hide a div on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm struggling to make an element first appear after a certain pixel scrolling down and then make it disappear after the same amount of pixels scrolled in the same direction. It should also disappear if going back above the trigger point that makes it appear and it should also always be centered in the page.

Right now my only problem is that the element is not disappearing when I keep scroll down but it does disappear when scrolling back to the top of the page.

This is the code that I'm using. Is there any quick way to make the element disappear again?

```js
var offsetTop = $("#second").offset().top;
var isVisible = false;
var scrollThreshold = 100; // Adjust this value as needed
var scrollDistance = 0;

// Get a reference to the element to show/hide
var $showElement = $("#show");

// Calculate the initial top position to center the element
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var elementHeight = $showElement.height();
var topPosition = (windowHeight - elementHeight) / 2;

// Set the initial CSS for the centered fixed element
$showElement.css({
  position: "fixed",
  top: topPosition + "px",
  left: "50%",
  transform: "translateX(-50%)",
  display: "none" // Start hidden
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scrollTop > offsetTop + scrollThreshold && !isVisible) {
    // If scrolled 100 pixels or more below the offset point and not visible, make it visible
    $showElement.fadeIn(200);
    isVisible = true;
    scrollDistance = scrollTop; // Record the scroll distance at which it became visible
  } else if (isVisible && (scrollTop <= scrollDistance - 200 || scrollTop <= offsetTop - scrollThreshold)) {
    // If scrolled 200 pixels or more above the point it became visible, or scrolled back above the initial threshold and currently visible, make it invisible
    $showElement.fadeOut(200);
    isVisible = false;
  }
});
```

```css
#first{
  height: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}

#second{
  height: 2800px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

#show{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="first">
  <h1>First</h1>
</section>

<section id="second">
  <h1>Second</h1>
  <div id="show"><pre>Hey!</pre></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#first{
    height: 200px;
    background: #eee;
}
#second{
    height: 2800px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#position{
    display: none;
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="first"> 
    <h1>First</h1> 
</section>

<section id="second"> 
    <h1>Second</h1>
    <div id="position"><pre>Hey!</pre></div> 
</section>
var offsetTop = $("#second").offset().top;
var isVisible = false;
var scrollThreshold = 100; // Adjust this value as needed
var scrollDistance = 0;

// Get a reference to the element to show/hide
var position = $("#position");

// Calculate the initial top position to center the element
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
// console.log( 'windowHeight: ' + windowHeight);

var elementHeight = position.height();

// console.log( '$showElement.height(): ' + $showElement.height());

var topPosition = (windowHeight - elementHeight) / 2;

// Set the initial CSS for the centered fixed element
position.css({
                    position: "fixed",
                    top: topPosition + "px",
                    left: "50%",
                    transform: "translateX(-50%)",
                    display: "none" // Start hidden
});

window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {

let scroll_y = this.scrollY;
let scroll_x = this.scrollX;
console.log(scroll_x, scroll_y);
if(scroll_y > 341){
    position.css('display','block');
}
if(scroll_y > 685)
    position.css('display','none');
});
```